# hydrateFn.apply(...) is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to migrate a webapp from react 18 to preact and I'm getting this error

**hydrateFn.apply(...) is undefined**

it happens with **next-mdx-remote**

this is the stack trace

```
./node_modules/next-mdx-remote/dist/index.js/MDXRemote/Content<@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_next-mdx-remote_index_js-node_modules_next-mdx-remote_serialize_js.iframe.bundle.js:38494:26
mountMemo@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:45650:19
useMemo@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:46095:16
useMemo@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:61025:21
MDXRemote@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_next-mdx-remote_index_js-node_modules_next-mdx-remote_serialize_js.iframe.bundle.js:38481:67
renderWithHooks@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:44730:27
mountIndeterminateComponent@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:48494:13
beginWork@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:50007:16
beginWork$1@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:55846:14
performUnitOfWork@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:54980:12
workLoopSync@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:54886:22
renderRootSync@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:54854:7
recoverFromConcurrentError@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:54270:34
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:54170:22
workLoop@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:62407:42
flushWork@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:62380:14
performWorkUntilDeadline@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:62674:21
EventHandlerNonNull*./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js/<@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:62712:3
./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:62774:5
__webpack_require__@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:28:33
fn@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:344:21
./node_modules/scheduler/index.js@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:62790:20
__webpack_require__@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:28:33
fn@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:344:21
./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js/<@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:28452:36
./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:58287:5
__webpack_require__@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:28:33
fn@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:344:21
./node_modules/react-dom/index.js@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:58364:20
__webpack_require__@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:28:33
fn@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:344:21
./node_modules/react-dom/client.js@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:58302:28
__webpack_require__@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:28:33
fn@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:344:21
./node_modules/@storybook/react-dom-shim/dist/react-18.mjs@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:1318:93
__webpack_require__@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:28:33
fn@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:344:21
./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/chunk-JWY6Y6NU.mjs@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:1345:102
__webpack_require__@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:28:33
fn@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:344:21
./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/config.mjs@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:1373:96
__webpack_require__@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:28:33
fn@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:344:21
./node_modules/@storybook/react/preview.js@http://localhost:3000/vendors-node_modules_storybook_addon-a11y_dist_preview_mjs-node_modules_storybook_addon-essen-d080cc.iframe.bundle.js:1439:93
__webpack_require__@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:28:33
fn@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:344:21
getProjectAnnotations@http://localhost:3000/main.iframe.bundle.js:2987:75
../../node_modules/synchronous-promise/index.js/_runResolutions/<@http://localhost:3000/sb-preview/runtime.js:4:80022
_runResolutions@http://localhost:3000/sb-preview/runtime.js:4:79963
then@http://localhost:3000/sb-preview/runtime.js:4:77505
getProjectAnnotationsOrRenderError@http://localhost:3000/sb-preview/runtime.js:81:13211
initialize@http://localhost:3000/sb-preview/runtime.js:81:12536
./storybook-config-entry.js@http://localhost:3000/main.iframe.bundle.js:3003:9
__webpack_require__@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:28:33
__webpack_exec__@http://localhost:3000/main.iframe.bundle.js:3122:67
@http://localhost:3000/main.iframe.bundle.js:3123:258
__webpack_require__.O@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:80:23
@http://localhost:3000/main.iframe.bundle.js:3124:56
webpackJsonpCallback@http://localhost:3000/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:1241:46
@http://localhost:3000/main.iframe.bundle.js:1:73
```

and these are the packages in package.json

```
"preact": "^10.18.1"
"react": "npm:@preact/compat"
"react-dom": "npm:@preact/compat"
"next-mdx-remote": "4.4.1"
```

any solutions or suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is not related with preact, it happens when the value of 'mdx' is null

<MDXRemote {...mdx}  />